# What would be a "night owl" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom

I'm looking for a good and idiomatic expression for a person who like to go to bed late at night.

P.S. This question is inspired by a similar question for the Latin language https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5349/what-would-be-a-night-owl-in-latin?noredirect=1&lq=1 that brought up really nice terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noktulo, noktemulo, noktovaganto.

Comment: noktostrigo? Would that work?

Comment: It could work given the right context, but it doesn't seem to be a common or even known expression in Esperanto.