# What would be a "lark" or "early bird" in Esperanto

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom

I am looking for a good and idiomatic expression for a person who gets up early in the morning (I hope for something different than *malstrigo*, c.f. [What would be a "night owl" in Esperanto?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/3468/what-would-be-a-night-owl-in-esperanto) although I must admit that *malstrigo* is idomatic in some way).

Comment: I for one really like the word ”malstrigo”. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fruema, fruemulo, frua leviĝanto, frua ellitiĝanto.